# Flask tutorial - Flask run gives an error - Python.exe: No module named flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-3.7

I am following the Flask tutorial from here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/ and foll. explains the issue I am facing:

Python Version: 3.7.4

[image: python version]

```
mkdir flask-tutorial
cd flask-tutorial

py -3 -m venv venv
venv\Scripts\activate

pip install Flask

mkdir flaskr
```

[image: Steps]

Now creating a new file in the flaskr folder with name `__init__.py` and code:

```
import os

from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    return app
```

[image: code]

Some Folders:
[image: folder structure]

pip list:

[image: pip list]

```
set FLASK_APP=flaskr
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

[image: output]

Comment: you need to add full project files, else you wont be able to run this, try to run just hello_world.py app

Comment: But its a step by step tutorial. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in your flaskr directory you need to add config.py and other files as mentioned in project and `__init__.py` file, just to start with flask , create a hello word.py file

Comment: app.config.from_pyfile() overrides the default configuration with values taken from the config.py file in the instance folder if it exists. Otherwise it uses defaults set in the init file

Comment: i followed the same step, i created virtualenv using `virtualenv`, rest is working fine for me , running flask run in parent directory of flaskr, in virtual env

Comment: Is there any error in the official tutorial then?

Comment: i tried with the offical tutorial also(creating virtual env), and this is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Even I got exactly the same situation and though I don't know the solution for the problem that is somehow due to set FLASK_ENV=development, I tried without setting it and didn't get any error. Hope this will help, will update if I got any solution.